# Гугл таблица. Сделать функцию NOW статической

Tags: таблицы

Что сейчас? Сейчас у нас есть гугл таблица, куда складывается каждая новая строчка в виде лида (имя, номер, дата, время и т.д)

Задача. Мониторить через сколько минут менеджер позвонил клиенту. Мы это видим так - менеджер тянул за уголок вниз в столбце (звонок), когда звонит клиенту, а мы при этом получали текущее время звонка и в следующем столбце мерим формулой успел он до 5 минут позвонить или нет.

Мы пробовали вставить функцию NOW() и она идеально подходит нам, если бы не одно НО. Она обновляется если потянуть ее вниз на следующую ячейку в стобце, а хотелось бы что она замерла.

Подскажите, как сделать функцию =NOW() в гугл таблице статической?

P.S: Да мы знаем что есть интрумент по правой кнопки мыши, отследить в какое время было что-то в ячейки, но это нужно каждый раз проверять в ручном режиме.

Comment: освойте гугл формы для операторов и будет счастье